# Google Analytics Data Feed API Error 414 URI Too Large

Tags: python, http, gdata, google-analytics-api

When using the google analytics data API with the python gdata library, we are assembling a GET request per the instructions in the documentation here: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html

We are running into problems however. As our requests get longer, we're occasionally getting a 414 error URI Too Large when we have a lot of filters.

Is there any way to use a POST request with the gdata API or otherwise get around the 414?

EDIT: Just tried using a POST request and get 403 Target feed is read-only. Is there any way around this restriction?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you submit the query from the data feed explorer: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html

Comment: It looks like it just dies silently, so presumably so. If I shorten the filters string it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 128 character limit on filters regardless of whether you're using GET or POST. Anything longer than that will result in a 400 error. The only way around that length limit is to use AND/OR boolean logic.

Here's the full explanation from Google:
[Rules for Filter Expressions](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html#filterExpressions)

Comment: At this point, I've researched this thoroughly and you appear to be correct that there is no solution. For anyone else with this problem, we were able to shorten our URLs somewhat by converting a long string of AND logic with == operators to use =~ regex operators instead.