# Google Analytics API too long filter

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

This is the class I'm using to connect to Google Analytics:
http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

What I need to do is, given a list of Wordpress posts, retrieve their visits. What I tried to do is to get the paths of the given posts and to use them as filters in the GAPI request, but I keep getting a 414 (URL too long).

This a chunk of my filter:

```
pagePath == /when-you-start-a-new-project-think-big || pagePath == /have-i-told-you-we-should-abolish-facebook || pagePath == /the-fourth-way-the-digital-knowledge || pagePath == /youtube-pages-load-without-css-how-to-solve || pagePath == /whats-wrong-with-android || pagePath == /how-facebook-is-killing-real-relationships || pagePath == /how-windows-8-is-the-clear-proof-that-microsoft-cant-lead || pagePath == /why-the-windows-linux-unified-kernel-is-a-bad-idea || pagePath == /post-pay-counter
```

Even with only 250 post paths, it triggers a 414 error, I guess due to the [128 chars limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7627247/917428). What I might do is to get from Analytics every row it has and then manage them on my own in PHP, but I guess it would get terribly slow! In what ways do you think I could solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you get all the data for all posts and then filter that later on your application?

Comment: I guess it would make the application quite slower... Imagine I need only the data of 20 records on a total of a thousand posts... It's much faster to request and handle only the data you really need instead of getting them all and then manage them, isn't it?

Comment: It is not. Simple queries run very fast on the API. The more complicated it gets the more it takes to run the query, even if it returns less data. Local filtering is of course very fast.

Comment: In this case that's great! Thanks, I'll fetch all the data and then filter it through PHP.